# Verb to use to describe a photograph "losing" its colors?

Tags: word-choice, verbs

At first I wanted to just write: "A photograph slowly losing its colors."

But I think *losing* isn't the right verb here. What can I use instead of *losing*? (I want to keep the word *colors*.)

Comment: *fade*; *discolor*

Comment: Photos 'fade'..

Comment: You **can** speak of things losing their colour, particularly when different colours fade at different rates: a colour photo might end up with faded blues but still-vibrant reds.

Comment: I'd say: "losing its color", because I think of "color" as a mass noun in this context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've said you want to keep the word "colors", I presume you want a transitive verb to fit into the sentence "A photograph slowly ing its colors".  If so, I would suggest the following:

- dissipating: a bit more forceful than losing
- shedding: slightly more poetic
- bleeding: more dramatic
- leaching: a little bit scientific, and more suitable for something
  else doing the leaching

To be honest, I think the sentence might be better rearranged, but I'm inferring from the way you worded the question that you don't want to do that.

Comment: Thanks! I'll choose one of those. I'm curious, how would you rearrange that sentence?

Comment: You can make the verb intransitive by making the colors the subject.  e.g. "the photo's colors slowly faded/dissipated"

Comment: Or even more idiomatically (to me, at least): “The colours (had) slowly faded from the photo”.

Comment: It would be beneficial to understand why my answer was downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

[*Desaturate*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/desaturate) is commonly used to refer to the loss of color in photos and of color in general.

> **desaturation** [diːˌsætʃəˈreɪʃən] *n* (Physics / General Physics)
>   *Physics* the addition of white light to a pure colour to produce a paler less saturated colour (TFD)

Comment: Though if you're talking about the effect of when a photo is old or has been in the sun too long, then you can say it has faded.

Comment: Why was this voted down?